# Choropleth Plotting issues with Plotly.express using geojson data and pandas data

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, plotly-python

I'm trying to visualize contaminants as a choropleth using plotly. I have a Geopandas dataframe with the density for each county of a given state, and a geojson file which provides the boundaries for each county in the state.

I tried following the example here: https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/
Plotly's example code (below) renders this image [image]:

```
    import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=geojson, color="Bergeron",
                    locations="district", featureidkey="properties.district",
                    projection="mercator"
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Using my data which should show all counties in the state of MI-USA I get stuck with the big blue box. The counties are read in (as shown in image here: [image]) but I can't figure out how to turn it into a county-based choropleth. *Note I have used plotly figure factory to render the image correctly, but I want to use this method since plotly.ff is deprecated for choropleths.

datafiles are here: https://github.com/MDJonesBYU/EGLE_Analysis.git

**Code below.**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
# Read the dataframe: 
df = pd.read_excel('contam_set.xlsx')

# Read the GeoJSON file
file = "Counties_(v17a).geojson"
with open(file) as data:
    geojson_data = json.load(data)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=geojson_data, color="Contam Density",
                    locations="County", featureidkey="properties.NAME",
                    projection="mercator"
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

**Thoughts/Suggestions**?
I am also open to using figure factory, but i ran into issues getting the county-level data to hover over.

Comment: I tried running the code with your data and got the same event. The most common problem in this case is a geometry problem in geojson. Please try with a different geojson file.